# Y axis labels won`t right align in shiny using ggiraph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggiraph

I cannot right align the y-axis labels in this **shiny app** using **ggiraph**.

Please find the running app here, a picture of the issue, the code, and app: https://eduardo757ag.shinyapps.io/test_labels/

I tried with **theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1))** to no avail.

Thanks for your help!

[image]

---

title: "test1"
author: "edu"
date: ''
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: tango
    theme: journal
runtime: shiny

---

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
library(shiny)
library(survey)

data(api)

api_test <- apiclus1 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(cname) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise_at(vars(acs.k3:acs.46), mean,na.rm=T) %>% 
  pivot_longer(2:3,names_to = "variable",values_to = "value") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(    
    IOMmission = 
      case_when(cname=="Alameda" ~ "A very very long long label, yes",
                T~cname))

api_test$tooltip <- c(paste0(api_test$cname, "\n", api_test$value))

shinyApp(

  # ui.R ----
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId = "Variable",
                        label = "Select a survey question",
                        choices= unique(api_test$variable)),

          width = 4,
          style = "font-family: 'Georgia'"),

        mainPanel(
          girafeOutput("mygplot1"),
          width = 8))
),

# server.R ----
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$mygplot1 <- renderGirafe({

      girafe(ggobj =

               ggplot(

                 api_test, aes(x= value , 
                               y=reorder(cname,value),
                               tooltip=tooltip,
                               data_id=cname)) +
        geom_bar_interactive(
          aes(alpha=.5),
          stat='identity',
          fill = "#56B4E9",
          data= api_test[api_test$variable == input$Variable, ]) +

          labs(
          y = NULL,
          x = "Average",

          caption = paste("Data X: ", api_test[api_test$variable == input$Variable, ]$value),
          title=input$Variable) +

          geom_vline(xintercept = 0, color="black", size=1) +

          scale_x_continuous(
               position = "top",
               labels = scales::number_format(suffix = "%"),
               expand = expand_scale(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +

          theme(
            axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1),
            plot.title.position = "plot",
            panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size = 1, colour = "grey80"),
            panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
            legend.position = "none",
            text=element_text(family="Georgia",size=12))
        ,
        height_svg=10,
        width_svg =8) %>%

        girafe_options(ggiraph::opts_hover(css="fill:#22222288;cursor:pointer;"))
  })},      
options = list(height = 740))
```

Comment: Can you read that chapter?https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/customizing.html#fonts Font "Georgia" must be available

Comment: Have you tried vjust = ? **theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1, vjust= *play around with numbers*))**

Comment: @DavidGohel if you look at the linked app you will see the font is not changed in that code. I recently saw the same bug, with and without setting any fonts.

Comment: @OlaCaster link has moved. https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/fonts.html - I disagree. Setting font help. The example upper don't set font so "Gorgia" must be in the machine running ggiraph and the reader (html side) must have Gorgia on his computer if not added in the CSS

Comment: @DavidGohel I think you misunderstood me. If you go to the OP's linked app at https://eduardo757ag.shinyapps.io/test_labels/ it is still up and running. That code (not the code here on SO) does not alter any fonts, and we still see this label misplacement.

Comment: @OlaCaster the issue is explained here: https://davidgohel.github.io/ggiraph/articles/offcran/fonts.html